# Rename duplicate files using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I'm trying to write a Python script that renames all duplicate file names recursively (i.e. inside all directories)
I already searched the web and Stack Overflow but I couldn't find any answer...
Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import os
import glob

path = os.getcwd()
file_list = []
duplicates={}

# remove filename duplicates
for file_path in glob.glob(path + "/**/*.c", recursive=True):
    file = file_path.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
    if file not in file_list:
        file_list.append(file)
    else:
        if file in duplicates.keys():
            duplicates[file] += 1
            lista = []
            lista.append(file_path)
            os.rename(file_path, file_path.rsplit('/', 1)[:-1] + '/' + str(duplicates[file]) + file)
        else:
            duplicates[file] = 1
            os.rename(file_path, file_path.rsplit('/', 1)[:-1] + '/' + str(duplicates[file]) + file)
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andre/Development/scripts/removeDuplicates.py", line 22, in <module>
    os.rename(file_path, file_path.rsplit('/', 1)[:-1] + '/' + str(duplicates[file]) + file)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

I know why I'm getting this error, but my question is: Is there a more clever way to do this? I'd also like to rename all duplicate directory names, but I still didn't figure it out...

Comment: You're looking for [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) to traverse your directory tree...

Comment: Thanks @AkshatMahajan ! That's really useful. But now, how do I change the filenames after seeing if it's duplicate or not? And how would I change the duplicate directory names?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, I think I can do this by myself haha

Comment: Just walk through the directory tree bottom up, keeping track of all the names you have seen so far in a directory inside a collections.Counter to identify which number you want to append. os.rename works for both directory paths and filename paths.

Comment: Thanks @AkshatMahajan !